# Highlight text in different colors - TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, textfield, highlight

Is there any way to highlight a specific part of a text inside a TextField in flutter like you can do in Microsoft Word?

Something like this but inside a Text Field in my flutter app:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at this: https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text ?

Comment: @Jacques But how do I use it inside a TextField?

Comment: It is not to use inside a TextField, it is a Widget that you could maybe use instead of TextField, if it fits your needs. The page I gave you explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way appears to be using a series of styled TextSpans.

Marc on Flutter Clutter has a really good tutorial on this:
https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/styling-parts-of-a-textfield/2021/101326/

Comment: What an incredible tutorial! Thanks for the link.